# Como enviar conteúdo de variável JQuery para uma textarea html?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Estou com bastante dificuldade em enviar o conteúdo de uma variável `JS` para um `<textarea>` (num modal bootstrap) e com a formatação XML definida na variável. Tanto o `JS` quanto a `textarea` estão num mesmo html. O código  é baseado nesse (que só gera resultados em html): http://www.yogihosting.com/implement-tmdb-api-with-jquery-ajax

Essa é a variável:

```
var xmlString = "<channel>" + "  <title><![CDATA[" + title + "|"+ to + "(" + ano + ")]]></title>" + "  <logo_30x30><![CDATA[" + image + "]]></logo_30x30>" + "  <description><![CDATA[<center><img height=\"254\" width=\"200\" src=\"" + poster + "\"</img><br>"+ sin +"</center>]]></description>" + "  <stream_url><![CDATA[" + escape(country) + "]]></stream_url>" + "  <subtitle><![CDATA[" + escape(zip) + "]]></subtitle>" + "</channel>";
```

E esta a textarea:

```
<textarea class="texto" id="ctext" name="ctext" cols="86" readOnly></textarea>
```

Alguém pode ajudar? Se houver sugestão para melhorar essa parte do código, será bem vinda.

Editei para incluir o código completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Busca no TMDb

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="apiDiv">
        <h4>Digite o Título do Filme em Qualquer Língua e Clique em Buscar</h4>
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Busca Filme no TMDb" />
        <button id="submit">Buscar</button><button id="reset">Limpar »</button>
        <div class="imageDiv">
            <img src="Image/loading.gif" />
        </div>
        <div id="message">
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul id="pagination"></ul>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitleH4"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalBodyDiv">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <p><textarea class="texto" id="ctext" name="ctext" cols="86"></textarea></p>
                <button class="button" id="clipboard" onclick="clipboard()">CopiarXML</button>
                <button id="bd" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Add MySQL</button>
                <button id="close" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.twbsPagination.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#reset").click(function (e) {
            location.reload();
        });

        $("#submit").click(function (e) {
            var validate = Validate();
            $("#message").html(validate);
            if (validate.length == 0) {
                CallAPI(1);
            }
        });

        $("#message").on("click", ".result", function () {
            var resourceId = $(this).attr("resourceId");
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + resourceId + "?append_to_response=credits&language=ptbr&include_image_language=pt-BR,null",
                data: {
                    api_key: ""
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    $("#modalTitleH4").html(result["name"]);

                    var title = result["title"] == null ? "No information available" : "" + result["title"];
                    var image = result["poster_path"] == null ? "Image/no-image.png" : "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + result["poster_path"];
                    var poster = result["backdrop_path"] == null ? "Image/no-image.png" : ""+ "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + result["backdrop_path"];
                    var to = result["original_title"] == null ? "No information available" : ""+ result["original_title"];
                    var sinopse = result["overview"] == null ? "No information available" : "" + result["overview"];
                    var ano = result["release_date"] == null ? "No information available" : ""+ result["release_date"];

                    var resultHtml = "<p class=\"text-center\"><img src=\"" + image + "\"/></p><p>" + title + "</p>" + to + "</p>" + poster + "</p>" + ano + "</p>" + sinopse + "</p>"; 

                    //resultxml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"+"<items>"+"\n<playlist_name><![CDATA["+"]]></playlist_name>"+"\n\t<channel>"+"\n\t\t<title><![CDATA[<font color=\"#ffff00\">"+title+ "|" + to + "(" + ano + ")" + "</font>]]></title>"+"\n\t\t<logo_30x30><![CDATA["+image+"]]></logo_30x30>"+"\n\t\t\<description><![CDATA[<center><img height=\"254\" width=\"200\" src=\""+poster+"\"/><center><br>" +sinopse+ "</center>]]></description>"+"\n\t\t<playlist_url><![CDATA["+"]]></playlist_url>"+"\n\t\t<stream_url><![CDATA["+"]]></stream_url>"+"\n\t\t<subtitle><![CDATA["+"]]></subtitle>"+"\n</channel>\n</items>";


                    $("#modalBodyDiv").html(resultHtml) +

                    $("#myModal").modal("show");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    $("#message").html("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
                }
            });
        });


        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $(".imageDiv img").show();
        });

        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            $(".imageDiv img").hide();
        });

        function CallAPI(page) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?language=pt-BR&query=" + $("#searchInput").val() + "&page=" + page + "&include_adult=false",
                data: { "api_key": "" },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    var resultHtml = $("<div class=\"resultDiv\"><p>Names</p>");
                    for (i = 0; i < result["results"].length; i++) {

                        var image = result["results"][i]["poster_path"] == null ? "Image/no-image.png" : "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + result["results"][i]["poster_path"];

                        resultHtml.append("<div class=\"result\" resourceId=\"" + result["results"][i]["id"] + "\">" + "<img src=\"" + image + "\" />" + "<p><a>" + result["results"][i]["title"] + "&nbsp; (" + result["results"][i]["release_date"] + ")" +"</a></p></div>");


                        var xmlString = "<channel>" + "  <title><![CDATA[" + title + "|"+ to + "(" + ano + ")]]></title>" + "  <logo_30x30><![CDATA[" + image + "]]></logo_30x30>" + "  <description><![CDATA[<center><img height=\"254\" width=\"200\" src=\"" + poster + "\"</img><br>"+ sinopse +"</center>]]></description>" + "  <stream_url><![CDATA[" + escape(country) + "]]></stream_url>" + "  <subtitle><![CDATA[" + escape(zip) + "]]></subtitle>" + "</channel>";

                        $("textarea#ctext").val(xmlString);  

                    }

                    resultHtml.append("</div>");
                    $("#message").html(resultHtml);

                    Paging(result["total_pages"]);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    $("#message").html("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
                }
            });
        }


        function Validate() {
            var errorMessage = "";
            if ($("#searchInput").val() == "") {
                errorMessage += "► Enter Search Text";
            }
            return errorMessage;
        }

        function Paging(totalPage) {
            var obj = $("#pagination").twbsPagination({
                totalPages: totalPage,
                visiblePages: 5,
                onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                    CallAPI(page);
                }
            });
        }


        function clipboard() {
            var x = document.getElementById("ctext").value;
            document.getElementById("modal-footer").innerHTML = x;
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Qual o erro que dá?

Comment: ÐvÐ Não acontece nada. Tentei usando  `$("#ctext").val(xmlString);`

Comment: Leo Caracciolo. Isso não funcionou comigo.

Comment: ÐvÐ Com texto envia sem problema (já tinha testado). Não funciona com variável

Comment: $("textarea#ctext").val(xmlString);

Comment: ÐvÐ com todas. Testei uma a uma. O curioso é que já existe uma outra variável que envia para o modal em html e funciona perfeitamente. O problema é enviar em formato texto para a textarea. Será que é preciso converter as variáveis em string antes?

Comment: Coloca as variaveis na pergunta

Comment: $("#ctext").val(xmlString); aqui comigo não funciona.O q funciona é `$("textarea#ctext").val(xmlString);`

Comment: coloquei uma função na resposta para trocar palavras acentuadas por não acentuadas para evitar o erro  `Result: error Internal Server Error 500 Internal Server Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**O código tem 2 problemas:**

1 - As variáveis `country` e `zip` não foram definidas no código

2 - Na função `function CallAPI(page) {` só tem definido `var image`

```
    var image = result["results"][i]["poster_path"] == null ? "Image/no-image.png" : "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + result["results"][i]["poster_path"];
```

falta definir as outras

```
var title = result["results"][i]["title"] == null ? "No information available" : "" + result["results"][i]["title"];
var poster = result["results"][i]["backdrop_path"] == null ? "Image/no-image.png" : ""+ "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + result["results"][i]["backdrop_path"];
var to = result["results"][i]["original_title"] == null ? "No information available" : ""+ result["results"][i]["original_title"];
var sinopse = result["results"][i]["overview"] == null ? "No information available" : "" + result["results"][i]["overview"];
var ano = result["results"][i]["release_date"] == null ? "No information available" : ""+ result["results"][i]["release_date"];
```

Para efeito de teste defini as variáveis country e zip na função `function CallAPI(page) {` dessa forma

```
var country = "Falta_definir_country"; 
var zip = "Falta_definir_zip";
var title = result["results"][i]["title"] == null ? "No information available" : "" + result["results"][i]["title"];
.......................
.......................
```

e veja   [**aqui**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/Como-enviar-conteudo-de-variavel-JQuery-para-uma-textarea.html) funcionando online

> Percebi que se digitar palavras acentuadas ocorre esse erro `Result: error Internal Server Error 500 Internal Server Error`

Para evitar esse tipo de erro ocorre colocar uma função que troca as letras acentuadas por letras sem acentos!!

**Eis aqui uma sugestão:**

coloque esse script no seu código

```
var letrasSemAcento = document.getElementById("searchInput");
    letrasSemAcento.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
    event.target.value = foldToASCII(event.target.value);
});
```

biblioteca

```
   <script src="seu_diretorio/fold-to-ascii.js"></script>
```

arquivo [fold-to-ascii.js - github](https://github.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii/blob/eae6030cc155a59fe7859666b4fb45171c67a17f/fold-to-ascii.js)

veja   [**aqui**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/Como-enviar-conteudo-de-variavel-JQuery-para-uma-textarea_letras_sem_acento.html) funcionando online

Comment: Leo Caracciolo, obrigado pela atenção. Como texto envia sem problema. Não sei se você percebeu que dentro de xmlString existem variáveis: `image`, `title`, etc. Com texto envia, mas o conteúdo dessas variáveis não.

Comment: @AntonioOliveira coloquei 2 variaveis

Comment: Leo Caracciolo. Muito estranho. Aqui não funcionou. Vou editar o post e colocar o código inteiro.

Comment: Leo Caracciolo não funcionou. editei e inclui o código completo.

Comment: @AntonioOliveira as variáveis country e zip não estão definidas

Comment: Refiz e funcionou. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser algo com as tags do seu xml. Nesse caso, tenta a fazer assim:

```
 $("textarea#ctext").html(xmlString);
```

Se não funcionar, posta o resultado de:

```
console.log(xmlString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro está nestas linhas:

```
var title = result["title"] == null ? "No information available" : "" + result["title"];
var image = result["poster_path"] == null ? "Image/no-image.png" : "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + result["poster_path"];
var poster = result["backdrop_path"] == null ? "Image/no-image.png" : ""+ "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + result["backdrop_path"];
var to = result["original_title"] == null ? "No information available" : ""+ result["original_title"];
var sinopse = result["overview"] == null ? "No information available" : "" + result["overview"];
var ano = result["release_date"] == null ? "No information available" : ""+ result["release_date"];
```

Quando você define variáveis com `var` dentro de uma função, essas variáveis só existirão dentro da própria função, e se você tentar acessa-las fora da função, irá gerar erro de **"variável não-definida"**.

Sendo assim, ao colocar essas variáveis fora da função onde elas estão nesta linha:

```
var xmlString = "<channel>" + "  <title><![CDATA[" + title + "|"+ to + "(" + ano + ")]]></title>" + "  <logo_30x30><![CDATA[" + image + "]]></logo_30x30>" + "  <description><![CDATA[<center><img height=\"254\" width=\"200\" src=\"" + poster + "\"</img><br>"+ sin +"</center>]]></description>" + "  <stream_url><![CDATA[" + escape(country) + "]]></stream_url>" + "  <subtitle><![CDATA[" + escape(zip) + "]]></subtitle>" + "</channel>";
```

irá gerar erro e nada acontecerá.

> Se você abrir o console (F12) do navegador, irá ver vários erros do
>   tipo ***title is not defined***, ***image is not defined***...

### Solução

Retire todos os `var` das variáveis, assim elas estarão acessíveis em outras partes do código (saiba mais sobre variáveis globais **[neste link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)**):

```
title = result["title"] == null ? "No information available" : "" + result["title"];
image = result["poster_path"] == null ? "Image/no-image.png" : "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + result["poster_path"];
poster = result["backdrop_path"] == null ? "Image/no-image.png" : ""+ "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + result["backdrop_path"];
to = result["original_title"] == null ? "No information available" : ""+ result["original_title"];
sinopse = result["overview"] == null ? "No information available" : "" + result["overview"];
ano = result["release_date"] == null ? "No information available" : ""+ result["release_date"];
```

### EDIT

Sem citar que as variáveis `country` e `zip` não existem no código (pelo menos no postado na pergunta).

Comment: Não funciona - Faltou o exemplo funcional :D veja sua solução http://kithomepage.com/sos/dvd.html